# Angular replays http calls when refresh token changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, firebase-authentication

I am facing a weird behavior in `Angular v6`. Probably I am missing something big while handing the subscriptions.

Whenever the refresh token expires (after some idle time without using the app), the app `replays` all the prior http events.

Following is what I do to reproduce the issue.

1. Login to my angular app and make some `N` http calls (`GET, POST and DELETE`)
2. Delete the `firebase refresh auth token` from `firebaseLocalStorage` indexedDB.

Step 2 triggers and replays all the http calls that I made in Step 1.

But it should't replay all past http events. What could be the reason ?

My http interceptor code is in https://gist.github.com/kumar-muthu/87c1404d3da48702739183e8d2c6e7d5

Note: I don't unsubscribe from the http observables, as I assume angular httpclient closes the subscrption once the http reponse is received.

Comment: how could you expect not to fail if you delete firebase refresh auth token from local storage? May be I couldn't understand your question

Comment: @Simonare edited it. The core problem is with the automatic replay of http calls. I want to know why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the interceptor. Instead of just taking the latest token, I had subscribed to the token. So every-time the token changes all prior http requests got replayed again.

https://gist.github.com/kumar-muthu/87c1404d3da48702739183e8d2c6e7d5#file-so_angular_http_inteceptor-ts-L47